# Get email account id in email on clicking link in email

Tags: c#, html, email

I have created a email template with a link on clicking the link its opens a url from which I identify which user has clicked on the link.

But when I have some other user in the cc or bcc of this mail they also get the same link and when they click on it shows as person in :to click on link.

Is their any way I can find our which exact user clicked on link.

**Example:**
**To:** a@gmail.com
**cc:** b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com
**Body**
**Link:** `<a href='mysite.com?user=a@gmail.com'>Click here</a>`

All three user will receive the same link, how can I find out which user has clicked on the link. Is their any way I can find out the current mail account id in my email template.

I am using .Net SMTP class for sending the mail.

Comment: No, there is no way. When everyone receives the exact same copy of the email there's no way to uniquely detect the clicker.

Comment: Thanks Chris for clarification, I was looking for workaround.

Comment: I've been doing email marketing professionally for 15+ years now so I can tell you with great confidence that there isn't a workaround. HTML is really just a hack on top of SMTP and for very good security reasons the former isn't even aware that it is being run in the context (or transport) of the latter.

Comment: Thanks Chris for such a solid statement and I was also not able to find out any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, since you're using SMTP, you can send individual emails to all of the recipients with specific links, instead of using CC or BCC.

**Example:**
**To:** a@gmail.com 
**Body
Link:** `<a href='mysite.com?user=a@gmail.com'>Click here</a>`

**To:** b@gmail.com 
**Body
Link:** `<a href='mysite.com?user=b@gmail.com'>Click here</a>`

**To:** c@gmail.com 
**Body
Link:** `<a href='mysite.com?user=c@gmail.com'>Click here</a>`

But, you can't detect the ***clicker*** by just using a static link.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for you solution Snazzy, but I don't want to really send every a mail in :to.

Comment: Then it's quite difficult.